Gcov generated coverage report confusion
I have the following piece of code that has been analyzed using gcov and gcovr, code is compiled with gcc with O0 optimization:

But I can't really understand why there are so many branches generated. Scouring the internet for answers I found out that gcov uses the compiler profiling, and this could be the case, but I still cannot understand why just simple assignents like m_record.m_campaignId = campaignId; would generate 2 branches(are there exception handling branches indeed being generated here?) and how could I fix/try to accomplish coverage here if I don't really know which branches are covered in the first place? Could it also be the fact that internal google test mock logic is also being analized and that also generates unwanted branches?

Yes, branches from exceptions are also counted. No, there's no easy way to skip counting them. Branch coverage for C++ code is just fundamentally difficult. You can play around with gcovr --exclude-throw-branches to stop counting some exception-only code, but this may also remove exception handlers. For details on this issue, see the gcovr FAQ: https://gcovr.com/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-c-code-have-so-many-uncovered-branches

@amon Maybe convert the comment to an answer.
